# Move zeroes to end of array in javascript - how to return nothing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am attempting to complete a [leetcode.com question](https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/) in JS.  I am new to algorithms in general, and am having some trouble getting my first submission accepted.

The question specifies the following:

Given an array `nums`, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

For example, given `nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]`, after calling your function, `nums` should be `[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`.

Note:
You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.
Minimize the total number of operations.

---

With that, here is my code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    var i, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
        if(nums[i] === 0) {
            temp = nums.splice(i, 1);
            nums.push(temp[0]);
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

The comments at the top of the code sample are provided in their text editor, and led me to believe that I am not supposed to provide any return statement.  Though the validator on their site seemed to not want to accept that at all, so I started returning null...

When I log my `nums` to the console after handling the input, I am seeing the desired result `nums = [1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`.  Regardless my answer keeps getting rejected.  I would love to understand what I am doing wrong here, so I can fix it.

I understand this may be a duplicate.  I saw other responses dealing with C and Java, but none I saw dealt with JS.

Comment: Remove the `return null` altogether.

Comment: 1) 'returning void', means : do not return anything. So just write 'return;' or do not write any return statement. 2) by using sort and the right sort function, you can write the answer in very little code.

Comment: Your loop should be going from the end to the beginning.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. I propose to change it to "How to let the return statement return nothing?" It would be better if you would not mention that the exercise is about sorting, so that readers can focus on the essence of your question.

Comment: I was wondering if you could totally remove the temp completely, and push(0) instead. So the lines inside if would be `nums.splice(i,1); nums.push(0)`.

Comment: Many answers (as well as this) use `splice`. Every call to `splice` is an O(n) operation, so inside a loop like this makes the algorithm O(n^2). Don't use `splice` if you want efficiency.

Comment: Filter all elements that are non zero and than push to the result `given.length - filtered.length` many zeros.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the return statement, the issue is your algorithm is wrong.

`[0,0,1,2,3]` will return `[0,1,2,3,0]`

When you loop in the positive direction and remove indexes, you skip indexes as the next index slides down to the position you already covered.

You need to loop in the negative direction. Start at the end and go to the start.

```
for (i = nums.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 9):

This is an O(n) solution to the problem:

```js
var moveZeroes = function (nums) {
  let count = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] !== 0) {
      nums[count++] = nums[i];
    }
  }

  for (let i = count; i < nums.length; i++) {
    nums[i] = 0;
  }
  
  return nums;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has already stated: when it says do not return anything, simply do not write a return statement.

However, there is a problem with your code. Use the test case [0,0,1].
If you start at the first element  so it moves it to the back of the array, [0,1,0]. Now your loop index is looking at the second element which is 1. you've completely missed the second 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(n) {
  // here i have created zeros array to store all zeros.
  let zeros = [];
  // here i filter out zeros first n array and push them at
  // same time to zeros array..
  n = n.filter(item => (item !== 0 ? true : zeros.push(item) && false))
  // finally i just max the zeros array at end of n array
  return n.concat(zeros)
}
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation what the code does and why it is better than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you must provide a return statement, but you are not allowed to return anything, you can just write

```
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Nothing in javascript

`null` is not nothing, technically. Try this: `typeof null`.  You get `"object"`, which is pretty much something. If you run a function that really doesn't return anything:

```
(function(){})();
```

You will see `undefined` in console. So either `return undefined` or just `return` or nothing at all will be considered OK.

#### Sorting alternative solution

I just want to propose more practical solution, to give you another point of view. Since it's javascript, you can use sort function. You will have to create your own callback to compare elements though:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) { ... comparison here ... });
```

Now in your specific case, what do we want? We state, that

> `a` is smaller than `b` **if and only if** `a` is zero and `b` is **not**  zero.

So our callback:

```
function(a, b) {
    if(a==0 && b!=0)
        return 1;
    else if(b==0 && a!=0)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Used like this:

```
var array = [2,6,0,666,-6,142,0,1,-10];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a==0 && b!=0)
            return 1;
        else if(b==0 && a!=0)
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    });
```

This is what we usually do when actually writing a program, because it's easier to understand (once you get used to it), and shorter most of the time.

Comment: array items are numbers. The sort function can be written function(a, b) { return (a*b ? 1 : ( b ? -1 : 0)); }

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice shortcut, good job. But even if that came to my mind, I wouldn't use it in answer because it's a little unclear at the first glance.

Comment: Sort is linearithmic, but we can do linear here. It's also assuming stability of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with ES6 Features

```
let filteredArr = nums.filter((elem) => {
    return elem !== 0;
}) // Create a new Array with all non zero elements

let countOfZero = nums.length - filteredArr.length // Get Count of Zero elements

let newArr = [...filteredArr,...Array(countOfZero).fill(0)] // Create a new array containig only zero equivalent to count of zero elements and filtered non zero elements Array 

return nums.splice(0,nums.length,...newArr) // Use splice to alter original array and then add new Array using spread operator
```

Answer (score 0):

This  approach can also be used. With two pointers

```js
function shift(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = arr.length - 1;

  while (j > i) {
    if (arr[i] === 0) {
      // swapping the numbers --->
      let last = arr[j];
      arr[j] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = last;
      j--;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }

  return;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 0, 7, 9, 0, 3, 0]
shift(arr)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each slot, and fill it will a value that comes from another index, one that moves ahead faster when it skips zeroes. The `??` operator can be used when that second index gets out of range:

```js
function moveZeroes(nums) {
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        while (nums[j] === 0) j++; // skip zeroes
        nums[i] = nums[j++] ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const moveZeros = (arr) => {
  const newArray = [];
  const allZeros = [];
  for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i] >= 1){
        newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }else{
      allZeros.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArray.concat(allZeros);
}

const zeros = moveZeros([1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 0]);
console.log(zeros);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function:

```
const shiftIt = array => {
    let temp = [...array];
    let zeroCounter=0;
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] === 0 ){
            array.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            i--
            zeroCounter ++
        }
        if(i+zeroCounter+1 === array.length) break;
    }
    return array
}

shiftIt([1,0,2,3,0,0,0,4]) // [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0]
```

Every time an element of array equals to zero, I send it to the end of array. So all of the other elements shift to left and I have to make i-- . We get stuck at infinity when all zeros go to the right side of the array. We consider the sum of these two conditions as the condition to exit the loop, since we know how many zeros there are and also where we are now is the end point of the non-zero elements.

Comment: It would be more helpfull if you can add some explanations

Comment: Every time an element of array equals to zero, I send it to the end of array. So all of the other elements shift to left and I have to make `i--` . 
We get stuck at infinity when all zeros go to the right side of the array. We consider the sum of these two conditions as the condition to exit the loop, since we know how many zeros there are and also where we are now is the end point of the non-zero elements.

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding this explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shared approach is not suitable for two or more consecutive zeros, below is example:

nums = [0,0,1]

- At index=0 output ==> [0,1,0]
- At index=1 output ==> [0,1,0]
  Here we are checking index 1 which is nonzero but we miss the 0 at index 0 and result gets messed up.

**Here is my approach to resolve the problem:**

```
   var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let len = nums.length
    if(len<=1)return nums
   let zeroCount=0;
   for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(nums[i]===0)zeroCount++
       else if(nums[i]!=0&&zeroCount!=0){
           nums[i-zeroCount]=nums[i]
           nums[i]= 0
       }
   } 
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the array by ascending order than loop from end to beginning to find zeros. 
When you find it, splice the array which will remove the current index and push zero

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  nums.sort((a,b) => {return a-b});
   for(let index = nums.length - 1; index >= 0 ; index--){
    if(nums[index] === 0){
      nums.splice(index, 1);
      nums.push(0);
    }
   }
};
```

Comment: `.splice` is linear so your overall algorithm is quadratic. Also `.sort()` kills the original order.

Answer (score -1):

```
function pushZerosToEnd(arr) {

            var k=0;

            for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] !==0)
                {
                    let temp=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[k];
                    arr[k]=temp;
                    k++;
                }
            }
            return arr;
    }
  console.log(pushZerosToEnd([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: Edit your answer indention and add a short explain to it.

Answer (score -1):

// javascript
// single array operation:

```
var a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0];
function moveZero(b) {
    for (var i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (b[i] === 0) {
            b.splice(i, 1);
            b.push(0);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
console.log(moveZero(a));
```

// multiple array operation => another approach
// algorithm: push all non zero elements in an array and all zeros in another array 
// concat them once loop terminates

```
var a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0];
var b = [];
var c = [];

function moveZero(data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i] !== 0) {
            b.push(data[i]);
        } else {
            c.push(0)
        }
    }
    if (c.length > 0) {
        b = b.concat(c);
    }
    return b;
}
console.log(moveZero(a));
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done this way too :

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    var len = nums.length, i = nums.indexOf(0);
    while(~i && i < --len){
        nums.splice(i, 1);
        nums.push(0);
        i = nums.indexOf(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this one**

```
 function order(array){
  count = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i] !== 0){
      //non zero element count
      array[count] = array[i]

      count++;


    }
  }

  while(count<array.length){

    array[count] = 0

    count++
  }

  return array
}
var array = [1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 6, 0]
console.log(order(array))
```

Comment: Why should we try this one? What makes it better than the existing answers? It seems like a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243478/6243352). Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple one

```js
function check(arr){
      var i=0;
      var j=arr.length-1;
      while(j>i+1){
        if(arr[i]!==0){
          i++;
        }
        if(arr[j]===0){
          j--;
        }
        if(arr[i]===0){
          arr[i]=arr[j];
          arr[j]=0;
        }
      }
     return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Splice() is used to remove the element (zero in this case). Then, push a zero to the end of the array.

```
 var moveZeroes = function (nums) {
  var length = nums.length;
  while (length-- > -1) {
    if (nums[length] == 0) nums.splice(length, 1).push(0);
  }
  return nums;
};
```

Comment: This removes the zeros from the array.

Comment: `.push(0);` does nothing here because it's operating on a temporary array that goes right to the garbage collector and is never assigned. I don't understand the point of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple solution:

**Time complexity O(n)**

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    var i = nums.length;
    while (i > -1) {
        let current = nums[i];
        if(nums[i] === 0) {
            nums.splice(i,1)
            nums.push(current)
        } 
       i--; 
    }
    return nums;
};
let arr = [0,1,0,3,12]
console.log(moveZeroes(arr))
```

Comment: Time complexity of `splice` is linear because it moves all of the elements forward, so the overall time complexity is O(n^2), not O(n).

Answer (score -1):

I would give alternate solution.
Remove the 0's then add them at the end.
Time Complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(1)

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let countZeros = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length;) 
    {
        if(nums[i] === 0) //remove zeros and increment the counter
        {
            nums.splice(i, 1);
            countZeros++;
        } 
        else // to deal with input which starts with 0 
        {
          i++;
        }      
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < countZeros; j++) //add zeros at the end
    {
        nums.push(0); 
    }
    return nums;
};
```

Comment: The time complexity is quadratic, not linear. `splice` requires all elements after `i` to be shifted forward to fill that gap. That's a linear operation, so nested in a loop gives O(n^2).

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1];
for(i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    x[i]!=0 && x.unshift(x.splice(i,1)[0])
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer adds to the other, accepted, or upvoted answers which are several years old.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, its just an one liner with array operator - neat & clean

Comment: Fair enough since the question is about a code golf type problem. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] === 0) {
            nums = nums.splice(i, 1);
            nums.push(0);
        }
    }
    return;
};
```

Comment: Why should they try this? Please explain how it works and why you think it's the best solution. Unfortunately, `splice` is linear, so you have an unnecessarily quadratic solution.

Answer (score -3):

Moving Zeros to End of Array with JAVA

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MoveZerosToEndWithJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] A = { 6, 8, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 1 };

        moving(A);
    }

    public static void moving(int[] a) {

        int countZero = 0;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 0) {
                countZero++;
            } else {
                if (i + 1 == a.length && countZero == 0) {
                    System.out.print(a[i] + "]");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < countZero; i++) {
            if (i + 1 == countZero) {
                System.out.print("0");
            } else
                System.out.print("0, ");
        }
        if (countZero > 0) {
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question, not Java.

Comment: First line says Moving Zeros to End of Array with JAVA. Thanks by the way

Comment: Ok? The fact that you said that doesn't make it any less irrelevant for a question about JavaScript.

Comment: This is for everyone who wants to use Java.

Comment: This is a question about how to do it in JavaScript. People looking at this question are going to want to know how to do it in JavaScript. If they want to know how to do it in Java, they're going to look for a question about Java.